# Is there a way to cache git credentials that doesn’t expire upon a machine restart?

Tags: git, ubuntu

There are a million posts here about how to cache credentials with git.  But none of them seem to hold if the machine does a reboot.  Is there a way to cache credentials that lasts upon machine restarts?

Comment: So, on Mac and Windows, yes, by tapping into the key chain or credential manager. The only way to do this safely is if you have an encrypted password database that is connected to your logging in to your computer. Is there something similar available on Ubuntu?

Comment: That being said, if you're using ssh connections to your Git repo, you can use an ssh key with an ssh agent. I have that setup somewhere, where I unlock my credentials by loading my ssh key into my ssh agent. I use that agent to login to my Ubuntu machine remotely, with agent forwarding enabled, and then I can use the same ssh key on GitHub. This will also work if you're working locally on that Ubuntu box, it just won't need forwarding.

Comment: Note that when the cache persists forever, it's called "storing". :-) There's a plain-text credential store included with Git, it's just dis-recommended because, well, plain-text password. Consider the libsecret method in [bk2204's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69789864/1256452), or my preferred method, use ssh instead.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, on Debian and Ubuntu, you can use the `libsecret` credential helper.  That will save the username and password or token in your desktop environment's key chain for future use.

Unfortunately, it is not built by default.  You can build it yourself by performing the following steps (assuming that `~/bin` in in your `PATH`):

```
$ cp -a /usr/share/doc/git/contrib/credential/libsecret /tmp
$ cd /tmp/libsecret
$ sudo apt install libsecret-1-dev libglib2.0-dev build-essential
$ make
$ cp git-credential-libsecret ~/bin
```

You can then do run `git config --global credential.helper libsecret`.  When you're prompted for your credentials, enter them as normal and then they will be saved indefinitely.  Note that they will be unlocked by default when you log in.

Comment: I’m getting `git: 'credential-libsecret' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.` when using git

Comment: You have to place the program in a directory in your `PATH`.  If you don't have `~/bin` in your `PATH`, then you either need to create the `~/bin` directory and edit your shell configuration to place it in your `PATH`, then run `exec bash` (or `exec zsh`, depending on shell), or copy it into `/usr/local/bin` with `sudo`.

Comment: Is the executable name **libsecret** or **git-credential-libsecret**?  FWIW, I tried both and both are in /usr/local/bin and it’s “seen” from my repo paths, but a simple git fetch returns `** (process:35449): CRITICAL **: 18:41:26.023: lookup failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.secrets was not provided by any .service files

** (process:35457): CRITICAL **: 18:41:26.117: store failed: The name org.freedesktop.secrets was not provided by any .service files`

Comment: The executable name is `git-credential-libsecret` and the config value is `libsecret`.  What desktop environment are you using?